# NUMBER OF WAYS TO GET XOR OF n NUMBERS TO BE 0

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

Alice and Bob are playing the game of Nim with $n$ piles of stones (p[0], p[1], ..., p[n-1]). If Alice plays first, she loses if and only if the 'xor sum' (or 'Nim sum') of the piles is zero, i.e. $p[0] ⊕ p[1] ⊕ ... p[n-1] = 0$

Bob can remove some stones in some piles before the game starts, but he must keep at least one pile unchanged. Your task is to count the number of ways Bob can remove the stones to force Alice into losing the game. Since the number can be very large, output the number of ways modulo (% operator) 1000000007. Assume that both players will try to optimize their strategy and try to win the game.

**Input**:

The first line of the input contains an integer $n$ denoting the number of piles. The next line contains a space separated list of number of stones $n$ for each pile p[0] p[1]... p[n-1] respectively.

**Output**:

An integer which is the *number of ways* % 1000000007 Bob can force Alice to lose the game.

**Constraints**:

$3 \leq n \leq 100$

$0 < p[i] < 10^9$

I thought that we can select the piles to be excluded in $2^{n}$-2 ways and depending upon the xor of these excluded piles, I need to find the number of arrangements such that the xor of included piles (piles which are modified) is odd/even accordingly. This has to be done for every bit to get 0. Moreover I cannot change a bit from 0 to 1 if it is to the right of the MSB/ or if MSB is set to 1.
Is this the correct way to think? or is there some other way

Comment: Sounds like a programming competition. You should tackle these on your own.

Comment: No it is not part of ongoing contest. It is for practice.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/stonegame

Comment: Oh, well, hacker rank is indeed a place where you can be scored by your ability to solve problems. It is great that you are using this problem just for practice (I do actually!) but making here a question and getting an answer amounts to kill the "aha!" moment for those that try the problem on their own as Yuval suggests (I beg you, please, to bear in mind that this is said with all respect, no offense implied!)

Comment: CarlosLinaresLópez Yes sir. I do understand that it would amount to cheating.But then I just wanted a hint so that i can solve the problem on my own.

Comment: Well, @TerenceHang seems to have gone along those lines indeed

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. each bit of xor result depends on all bits on that position only. So each bit can be processed independently, while ignoring the unchanged constraint.
2. process bits from MSB to LSB, the higher bits impact the range of each lower bit.
3. during the processing of last step, you can easily track whether a pile is changed or not.
4. $O(2^n)$ is too slow when $n=100$, try dynamic programming.

Comment: I am not being able to formulate the dp. So if I count the number of positions where I can place a 1 in case of a particular bit i( the number of positions being the numbers for whom i<MSB. Let it be M), then number of ways we can get even 1s is 2^(M-1).But we cannot add a 1 to a number at bit i if its MSB is set to 1 as we need to reduce the number.